# Can I read subcollections and documents in a document without separately reading it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

```
 componentDidMount(){
    dbh.collection('Groups').get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            this.setState({
                groups: [...this.state.groups,doc.data()],
            })
        })
    })
}
```

I have read a document from Firestore. However, this document contains a subcollection (Sessions) that contains a number of documents. is there a way to read the document with its subcollections and subdocuments? and store them in the state?
at the moment I am only able to see the elements of the read document without its subcollections and subdocuments.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> is there a way to read the document with its subcollections and subdocuments?

It's not possible with a single query.  You will have to query each subcollection separately.

Firestore queries are always shallow, and don't consider documents outside of a single collection.  In a general sense the pattern is like this:

```
    dbh.collection('Groups').get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.docs.map(snapshot => {
            return dbh
                .collection('Groups')
                .doc(snapshot.id)
                .collection('whatever')
                .get()
        })
    })
    .then(results => {
        this.setState(...)
    })
```

You can see that you'll have to chain your queries together using promises, then set the state after everything is available.

Comment: So is the total # of reads = (# of Groups) x (#of whatever) ??

Answer (score 0):

You can access subcollections of documents by using the following query syntax: `dbh.collection('Groups/{groupId}/users')`

Where `{groupId}` would be your document, and `users` the subcollection.

You could then store this in the state for that group.